# Is Prolog suitable for this kind of project?

Tags: prolog, logic

I am working on a project where I have to build an engine that is able to generate a bunch of premises and, given a true fact, tell what else can be deduced. Example given:

```
If John plays football then Mary makes cookies.
If Eric listens to rock then john doesn't play Football.
If Eric doesn't listen to rock then john plays Football.
Either Eric listens to rock or Luiza listens to rock.
```

When the given true fact is "Luiza listens to rock", then the solution should be:

```
Eric listens to rock = false
John plays football = true
Mary makes cookies = true
```

When the true fact is "Eric listens to rock", then the solution should be:

```
Luiza listens to rock = false
Jonh plays football = false
Mary makes cookies = (can't solve)
```

When the true fact is "John plays football", then the solution should be:

```
Mary makes cookies = true
Luiza listens to rock = (can't solve)
Jonh plays football = (can't solve)
```

**Question**: is Prolog the correct tool for solving this kind of problem? Code examples are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Prolog would be awesome for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Prolog would be awesome for this.

Here's an example of a similar problem:

```
/*
1. Mr. K made his sighting at some point earlier in the week than the one who saw the balloon, but at some point later in the week, than the one who spotted the Kite ( who isn't Ms. G ).
2. Friday's sighting was made by either Ms. Barn or the one who saw a plane ( or both ).
3. Mr. Nik did not make his sighting on Tuesday.
4. Mr. K isn't the one whose object turned out to be a telephone pole.
*/

?-
% Set up a list of lists to be the final solution
        Days = [[tuesday,_,_],[wednesday,_,_],[thursday,_,_],[friday,_,_]],
/* 1 */ before([_,mr_k,_],[_,_,balloon],Days),
/* 1 */ before([_,_,kite],[_,mr_k,_],Days),
/* 2 */ (member([friday,ms_barn,_],Days);
            member([friday,_,plane],Days);
            member([friday,ms_barn,plane],Days)),
% Fill in the rest of the people
        members([[_,mr_k,_],[_,ms_barn,_],[_,ms_g,_],[_,mr_nik,_]],Days),
% Fill in the rest of the objects
        members([[_,_,balloon],[_,_,kite],[_,_,plane],[_,_,tele_pole]],Days),
% Negations should be done after the solution is populated
/* 1 */ member([_,NOT_ms_g,kite],Days), NOT_ms_g \= ms_g,
/* 3 */ member([tuesday,NOT_mr_nik,_],Days), NOT_mr_nik \= mr_nik,
/* 4 */ member([_,NOT_mr_k,tele_pole],Days), NOT_mr_k \= mr_k,
    write(Days),
    nl,
    fail.

% Checks that `X` comes before `Y`
% in the list `Ds`
before(X,Y,Ds) :-
    remainder(X,Ds,Rs),
    member(Y,Rs).

% Finds a member of a list and
% unifies the third parameter such
% that it is the remaining elements in
% the list after the found member
remainder(X,[X|Ds],Ds).
remainder(X,[_|Ds],Rs) :- remainder(X,Ds,Rs).

% An extended version of `member` that
% checks if the members of the first list
% are all members of the second
members([],_).
members([X|Xs],Ds) :-
    member(X,Ds),
    members(Xs,Ds).
```

It produces the following result:

```
[[tuesday, ms_g, tele_pole], [wednesday, mr_nik, kite], [thursday, mr_k, plane], [friday, ms_barn, balloon]]
```